# What is "site" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin, modern-life, technology

I have been using the simple-minded translation *situs* (fourth declension) for "[web]site", and I have used it to refer to this site, among others.
I'm not convinced this is a good choice, as I have no other real motivation for it than the similarity to the English word.
What word would you suggest using and why?
It can very well be the same word, but I would like to know why it is (or is not) suitable.

Answer (score 2):

A dozen or more years ago, I ran a website using *locus intextus*. This format seemed at the time to be widely acceptable, though it had rivals based on, for instance, *interrete*.

My site (now long defunct) opened with the introductory page-heading *Salve! aspicis nunc locum intextum PHASELUS* etc. In about ten years of operation in different editions, this descriptor drew no adverse comment and was, indeed, sometimes commended.