# Latin word for 'the web' or 'Internet'

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, contemporary-latin, modern-life, technology

How would I refer to 'the web' or 'Internet' in Latin?

Many words to describe the internet are just reapplied from other objects (e.g. 'page' from a book or 'site' as in a location).  Translating these is pretty straightforward (*page* is just *pagina*).  But is there a word to use to specifically describe the internet (e.g. to say 'web page' or 'page of the web')?

Comment: There is already a [question about "website"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5573/79). Would it make sense to narrow this one down to just web pages?

Comment: Vicipaedia uses _pagina_ to describe a page on their website. I did just some minor searching and I am a bit surprised that there is no accepted term for a website already...

Comment: @jpyams How you choose to redefine the question is your call. Webpage, internet, net, web, and many other words make good questions, but I wouldn't lump them all together.

Comment: Immediate thoughts are "tela" and "interreta" but I don't remember where those are from

Answer (score 5):

The word I have always used and often seen in use for the internet is ***interrete***.
The third declension neuter *rete* means "net".
A *rete* can be used for catching animals or [fighting on the arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiarius).

The prefix *inter-* is of course of Latin origin, so it makes sense to translate "inter-net" as *inter-rete*.
By analogy to the ancient net-fighter, I like calling internet users *interretiarii*.
Another natural derivative is the adjective *interretialis*, which can be used to describe a "web page", *pagina interretialis*.
The page in this context is clearly an extension of the page of a book, and *pagina* is the perfect word for that purpose.

If you want to refer to a network other than the internet, one option is [*nexus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DN%3Aentry+group%3D12%3Aentry%3Dnexus2).
That word is often used as a translation for "link", though, so it might be confusing.
Perhaps the best general word for "network" or "web" is simply *rete*.

One option is to use the word *tela* (a spider's web), but I prefer *interrete* because the prefix reminds of the same word in other languages, whereas *tela* can be harder to grasp if you have never heard it before.
As always with technology, there is no single canonical correct translation to Latin.

Comment: There was a vogue some years ago for the abbreviation 'ttt', to be used instead of 'www', though I believe it came to nothing. It stood for either _tela totius telluris_ or _tela totius terrae_, according to your fancy.

Comment: @TomCotton I think I was taught at some point that the world wide web and the internet were two different things, so I do not know if ttt and interrete synonyms exactly.

Comment: @Sam K Both 'www' and 'ttt' mean(t) 'world wide web'. We all seem to use 'web' and 'net' interchangeably nowadays as shorthand for 'internet' and, if there really be a technical distinction, I have the impression that it's disappeared among lay users.  I used to call my own, long-defunct website a _locus intextus_, which was posted on the _interrete_.

Comment: @TomCotton: I know the abbreviation *ttt* from Esperanto, there it means *tut-tera teksaĵo* (a very similar idea to the Latin one you quote)

Comment: @TomCotton Perhaps it is just a technical distinction then. I like both terms, so I guess I was just trying to find a way to preserve them both! If you want to go down that technical rabbit hole, here are the Wikipedia articles on them: [Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) & [World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web)...

Comment: @Sam K 'Technical rabbit hole' — I do like that: all a Wonderland!